# Get all delegated contacts via API

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api

I need to get all delegated google contacts through API.

Delegated contacts(shared by one user to another user)? are shown under the label delegated->  in GMail.

I need to get contacts which are delegated to me by my co-worker through the API.